# How do I morph two complex objects? Is it possible for them to end up with the same Vertex and Polygon count?

Tags: mesh, unreal-engine

I'm new to blender and I wanted to understand how I can morph two different complex objects. Mainly I would like to find a way to make the vertices and polygons match so I can morph them in Unreal engine. The tutorials I've stumbled upon only worked for non complex objects like simple shapes and I couldn't really find much on how to make two different objects have the same amount of vertices and polygons.

Any guidance would be appreciated[image: ![]I attached a picture to show the amount of vertices and polygons if that helps][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtVSh.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried shape keys?

Comment: Hi I have and it seems to only turn into the back legs of the model and I'm not sure why. Also its my first time posting and not too sure how to add another picture but I'll try editing the post to show the results of me using shape keys.

Comment: I would mix a rigged character (parent each limb to a bone) with shape keys, so that you can both move the limbs (so that you can switch from a pose to another) and morph them

Comment: Thanks! This does sounds like something that would would work but also a little complex since I'm still learning blender. But I guess I will try and figure it out. The Cougar model has bones but the humanoid model I've imported doesn't so I'll reimport one that has bones and try to figure out how to implement what you just said.

Comment: you need to use one armature only, and create a Rest pose, either for the human, or for the animal, depending on which one will be the main character

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to do it in Unreal Engine unless you want to do it there when you can do it in **Blender.**

You have **two** options to do it in Blender:

## The Boolean Union

Select one of your objects. Add a boolean modifier to it. Set the boolean modifier to `Union`. Then, select your other object as the target object. This will join the objects together.

[image]

## Remesh

Select both your objects in `Object Mode`. Press `Ctrl` + `J` to join. Now go into sculpt mode. On the top bar, you will see a dropdown menu called `Remesh`. You can play with the settings (The lower the voxel size the higher polys your mesh will have) and then press the `Remesh` button to get your result.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response and I did try both suggestions but they don't achieve what I'm going for.

Also sorry if I wasn't very clear in the outcome I wanted. So I mentioned unreal engine because I would like the player character to be able morph into the cougar and they would also be able to morph back into the humanoid character. 

I've seen a post where someone achieved doing what I mentioned and they stated both models MUST match with same Vertices and Poly count. I've also tried shape keys and the morph didn't work at all. The Humanoid character only morphed into the back legs.